# JQuery - Displaying hidden text field in form within modal after selecting option in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to scripting and trying to understand it better. I have a modal being displayed after clicking a button that has a form inside of it. There is a dropdown box with two selections. The first selection (Single) is meant for all divs and text fields to be displayed with the exception of the Guest text fields since they will be coming alone without a guest.

What I am trying to do is make the text fields show up once the second option (Couple) is selected so that the Guest name fields can be entered, and I can't seem to get them to display so that text can be entered. Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group" id="selector">
    <label for"selection" class="col-xs-8" control-label>Will you be joining us with a guest?</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selection" name="amount">
        <option value="40.00">Single - $40.00</option>
        <option value="75.00">Couple - $75.00</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="first_name" class="col-xs-4" control-label>First Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="First Name">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name"
            name="os0" placeholder="i.e. John" required autofocus>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="last_name" class="col-xs-4" control-label>Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Last Name">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name"
            name="os1" placeholder="i.e. Smith" required autofocus>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="guestFirst">
    <label for="guestFirstName" class="col-xs-4" control-label>Guest's First Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8" style="display: none">
        <input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Guest's First Name">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="guestFirstName" name="os3"
            placeholder="i.e. Jane" autofocus>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="guestLast">
    <label for="guestLastName" class="col-xs-4" control-label>Guest's Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="on4" value="Guest's Last Name">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="guestLastName" name="os4"
            placeholder="i.e. Smith" autofocus>
    </div>
</div>

-----

<script>
    $('#selection').on('change', function() {
     if ( this.value == '75.00')
     {
       $("#guestFirstName").show();
     }
     else
    {
      $("#guestFirstName").hide();
    }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** you set the input field to display via jQuery but set display:none property to the col-xs-8 before that input filed.

**Solution:** I think you need to hide the div id #guestFirst, #guestLast and show them after select couple from dropdown.

So set those div style display none using css. then show those divs using if else condition on jQuery.
[LiveOnFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp005kvL/)

```js
 $('#selection').on('change', function() {
 if ( this.value == '75.00')
 {
   $("#guestFirst, #guestLast").show();
 }
 else
{
  $("#guestFirst, #guestLast").hide();
}
});
```

```css
#guestFirst, #guestLast{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group" id="selector">
<label for="selection" class="col-xs-8" control-label>Will you be joining us with a guest?</label>
<select class="form-control" id="selection" name="amount">
    <option value="40.00">Single - $40.00</option>
    <option value="75.00">Couple - $75.00</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="first_name" class="col-xs-4" control-label>First Name</label>
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="First Name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name"
        name="os0" placeholder="i.e. John" required autofocus>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="last_name" class="col-xs-4" control-label>Last Name</label>
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Last Name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name"
        name="os1" placeholder="i.e. Smith" required autofocus>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="guestFirst">
<label for="guestFirstName" class="col-xs-4" control-label>Guest's First Name</label>
<div class="col-xs-8" >
    <input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Guest's First Name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="guestFirstName" name="os3" 
        placeholder="i.e. Jane" autofocus>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="guestLast">
<label for="guestLastName" class="col-xs-4" control-label>Guest's Last Name</label>
<div class="col-xs-8" >
    <input type="hidden" name="on4" value="Guest's Last Name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="guestLastName" name="os4" 
        placeholder="i.e. Smith" autofocus>
</div>
</div>
```